# How To Replace Pixel color with other color in Image?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I have an Image and I can Read all it's Pixels colors using Martix ... How can I change The RGB for any Pixel If I want to convert it to the nearest color from (Black , Red or white)

My Code to Read the Image in Matrix is :

```
string sourceimg = @"D:\ProductionTools\Taskes\Image Processing\Test\001.jpg";
//...
Bitmap imageoriginal = new Bitmap(sourceimg);
int height = imageoriginal.Height;
int width = imageoriginal.Width;
Color[][] colormatrix = new Color[width][];
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    colormatrix[i] = new Color[height];
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        colormatrix[i][j] = new Color();
        colormatrix[i][j] = imageoriginal.GetPixel(i, j);
    }
}
```

Comment: @DmitryG: Although it's good of you to fix OP's indenting, please don't take it upon yourself to "fix" his bracing style.

Comment: Your question is actually about color distance, which is problematic to do in RGB. If you use the typical euclidean distance between the triples `(R1, G1, B2)` and `(R2, G2, B2)`, you will have trouble even with this simple application. Also, is `(128, 128, 128)` closer to black `(0, 0, 0)` or to white `(255, 255, 255)` ?

Comment: @Rawling i've just using my formatting tool... anyway, i will try to follow with this recommendation in future

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in your comments, the question is about color distance, which is not a trivial matter. It also relates to which colorspace you use, so here I will show you examples in RGB, HSV, HLS, and CIELAB. Also, to calculate distance you need a formula. For simplicity, let's sticky to the euclidean distance, as in [image]

Then to trivially answer your question, you calculate the distance from the current color `q` to the three targets `pi` you have (black, red, and white). The smallest distance indicates the color you replace with. In case of tie, I keep the earliest color that gave the minimum distance.

Now, the colorspace is also very important in this task since it establishes the meaning for the euclidean distance. Here is a sample image:

[image]

Converted in RGB:

[image]

Converted in HLS (i.e., the RGB color is converted to HLS and the distance is calculated):

[image]

HSV:

[image]

CIELAB:

[image]

Comment: I particularly like the results in CIELAB.

Comment: My code gives a result most like your HSV, I think. NB on your "hue" axis, are you remembering to wrap it around?

Comment: @Rawling do you mean in the sense to consider that blue hue is closer to red than to a green hue ? I didn't, it was a direct dummy euclidean distance between triples, which doesn't consider particular behavior of color spaces.

Comment: Fair enough... as red is usually zero hue there are some very-slightly-purply reds that are probably set to black or white, then.

Comment: Well, yes. In that case, you are using a specific distance for a specific color system, which is fine (and could produce better results). For CIELAB, the simplest Delta E function is the euclidean distance, so that could be another reason for why I find the results better in this color space (the distance function matches what the color space indicates as distance). The problem is that I'm not aware of any globally accepted distance functions for other color systems.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, the hardest part of this problem is knowing whether a given color is "closer" to black, white or red. I've thrown something together that might work for you:

```
Color GetNearestOfBWR(Color c)
{
     float redness = Math.Abs(180 - c.GetHue()) / 180;
     float brightness = c.GetBrightness();
     float saturation = c.GetSaturation();
```

You now have three values, each between 0 and 1, where increasing from 0 to 1 means you are getting closer to red (roughly speaking: more red/less green&blue, more color/less black, more color/less grey).

You now have to decide at what point a color constitutes "red" and honestly that's a judgment call. You could simply have

```
     double brightColourfulRedness = Math.Sqrt(
         redness*redness + brightness*brightness + saturation*saturation);
     if (brightColourfulRedness > 1)
         return Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0); // red;
```

(simple Euclidean norm) but you might want to weight a particular property more strongly than another - or simply modify the `1` threshold.

Then you have to decide what maps to black or to white; this could be as simple as

```
    if (brightness > 0.5)
        return Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255); // white
    return Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0); // black
}
```

Great! So now you have a function to map a color to red, white or black, according to taste. All that remains is to apply it to each pixel in your bitmap. If you're happy overwriting the `Bitmap` you loaded from your file, you don't need the array; you can just do:

```
int height = imageoriginal.Height;
int width = imageoriginal.Width;
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        Color origC = imageoriginal.GetPixel(i, j);
        Color newC = GetNearestOfBWR(origC);
        imageoriginal.SetPixel(i, j, newC);
    }
}
```

This can be quite slow, so you could alternatively use DmitryG's `LockBits` code, but you'd need to convert between the `int`s it gives you and the `Color`s required by `GetNearestOfBWR`. (`FromArgb` and `ToArgb` do this, I believe.)